# How to convert array in controller to string in views in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a controller which passes an array data to view. Inside the view, I wanted to use the data as string in JSON object format.

Here is my controller:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
  private $user;

  public function index()
  { 
    return view('app')->with([
        'userdata' => array('user' => 'John', 'age' => 20), 
        'access_token' => 'token_here'
    ]);
   }
}
```

Here is my view app.php

```
 <html>
 <-- more html codes--->
 <script>
  let userdata = "{{ $userdata }}"; // ERROR: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given 
 </script>
 <-- more html codes--->
 </html>
```

I tried using implode,

```
<script>
    let userdata = "{{ implode(' ', $userdata)";
    console.log(userdata);
</script>
```

It didn't have an error, but the problem is, the result becomes:

```
{&quot;userdata&quot;:{&quotuser&quot .....}
```

How can I have a correct result like this:

```
{'userdata': {'user':'john', 'age': 20}...} // this should be a string
```

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `json_encode`:

```
{!! json_encode($userdata) !!}
```

> note that you have to use `{!! !!}` to get exact string what you want. strings placed in `{{ }}` are escaped

Also you can user blade directive `@json` . depends which version of laravel you are using:

```
@json($userdata)
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Laravel blade docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade).

**Rendering JSON**

Sometimes you may pass an array to your view with the intention of rendering it as JSON in order to initialize a JavaScript variable. For example:

```
<script>
    var app = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
</script>
```

However, instead of manually calling json_encode, you may use the @json Blade directive. The @json directive accepts the same arguments as PHP's json_encode function:

```
<script>
    var app = @json($array);

    var app = @json($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I got this. But, you have to set JSON.stringify(app) since the problem needs to be a string. Please add the code and I will accept it. thank you very much